# Proof criticize: rank $n$ vector bundle on $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ is trivial

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles, schemes, affine-schemes

The problem stated in the title comes from Vakil's AG notes 14.3.C. I am aware that there are few similar questions answered here. But I wish to give my own proof that I am not so sure if is valid. Firstly, let $\mathcal{F}$ be a locally free sheaf on $X=\mathbb{A}^1_k$ of rank $n$. Let me give a lemma that will be used.

**Lemma (Geometry of Schemes, Corollary I-14).** Let $\mathscr{U}$ be an open covering of a topological space $X$. If $\mathscr{F}_U$ is a sheaf on $U$ for each $U\in\mathscr{U}$, and if they agree on overlaps and satisfy cocycle conditions. There exists a unique sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ on $X$ such that $\mathscr{F}|_U\cong \mathscr{F}_U$ and such isomorphism respects inclusions.

**Proof.** Since $\mathcal{F}$ is locally free on $\mathbb{A}^1_k$, we see that it is quasi-coherent, which implies $\mathcal{F}\cong\widetilde{M}$ for some $k[x]$-module $M$. Assume $\{U_i\}$ is a trivialization cover of $\mathcal{F}$ over $X$. We can find some $\{D(f)\}$'s so that they cover these $U_i$. So one has
$$\Gamma(D(f),\mathcal{F})\cong\Gamma(D(f),\widetilde{M})\cong\Gamma(D(f),\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^1_k}^n)\cong k[x]_f^n$$
We can extend these local information to a unique sheaf according to the lemma. Now our candidate is simply $\widetilde{k[x]^n}$, the uniqueness tells us this is exactly $\widetilde{M}$. Hence
$$\mathcal{F}(X)\cong\widetilde{M}(X)=k[x]^n$$

Please give your critique freely. Thank you very much!

Comment: Your proof is millimeters away from showing that all locally free sheaves are isomorphic, which is clearly false on an arbitrary scheme (ex:$\Bbb P^n$ and $\mathcal{O}(d)$ as $d$ varies). You have serious work to do to salvage this proof.

Comment: @HankScorpio Thank you for your comment! I do not find it perfect but I am not sure where went wrong. Do you mind pointing it out?

Comment: It's much better to use the structure theorem for fg modules over a PID, like Alex Kruckman's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4720012/classify-all-coherent-sheaves-on-mathbba1-k?rq=1).

Comment: @HankScorpio Thank you for the reference. I do know a proof using the structure theorem. This post is only for critique, as I am not sure where went wrong. It would be great if you could point that out.

Comment: @Mizutsuki - have you done the exercise on "glueing of sheaves"? This exercise is essential for this problem. Your sheaf is locally on the form $k[x]^{n_i}_{f_i}$ for polynomials $f_1,..,f_r \in k[x]$ generating the unit ideal $(f_i)=(1)$. You must prove there is for each integer $n \geq 1$ only one such locally trivial sheaf.

Comment: @hm2020 Yes I have. I think I know how to do it that way. But I am interested in correcting this proof I gave. By using the lemma, or possibly https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00AK Because this proof does not really use the discussion of finitely generated module over PID. I want to see the reason it fails.

Comment: The error is playing fast and loose with what local information needs to agree. You need to keep track of not just the local isomorphism classes but the actual gluing data/isomorphisms on overlaps. You seem to be ignoring this point (which stems from the imprecision in the lemma statement) and this is where your issue lies. You have only verified your F locally has the same isomorphism type as the trivial vector bundle F', but have said nothing about comparing the gluing data on overlaps.

Comment: @Mizutsuki - It "sounds like" you must use the cocycle condition to get conditions on the glueing maps. If $U_i:=D(f_i)$ is an open cover and if you are given local isomorphisms $\phi_i: F_i \cong k[x]^n_{f_i}$, this should somehow be related to units in the ring $k[x]_{f_if_j}$. You may calculate the units in this ring and the cocycle conditions should put strong restrictions on the maps $\phi_i$.

Comment: @Mizutsuki - The  PID approach has nothing to do with algebraic geometry. It is better to understand the cocycle condition and how to glue sheaves.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsor_(algebraic_geometry) - this is related to the notion "torsor" - the exercise asks you to classify $GL_n$-torsors on $k[x]$.

Comment: @AlexYoucis and hm2020. Indeed I was not paying much attention to the cocycle condition. Because $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf already, which should satisfy those conditions. And the quasicoherent condition just allows us to "guess" such module. Doesn't it work this way?

Comment: @Mizutsuki - An approach could be to start with an open cover $U_i:=D(f_i)$ of $C:=\mathbb{A}^1_k$ and to define free rank $n$ modules on each $U_i$, and to try to glue these to a rank $n$ locally trivial sheaf on $C$. This is where the cocycle condition appears - when you try to glue these to a locally trivial rank n sheaf on $C$ you will get restrictions on the maps involved.

Comment: @hm2020 In this problem, $\mathcal{F}_U$ all come from the sheaf $\mathcal{F}$. Then why do we still need to verify the cocycle condition to glue them?